# Esapi WARNING: [SECURITY FAILURE Anonymous:null@unknown -> /ExampleApplication/IntrusionDetector]

Tags: esapi

I have this line of code:

```
ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("user id", userID, "USERID", 8, false);
```

I have written a test for it, when I run the test and the test fails I get the following warining:

```
WARNING: [SECURITY FAILURE Anonymous:null@unknown -> /ExampleApplication/IntrusionDetector] Input exceeds maximum allowed length of 8 by 5 characters: context=user id, type=USERID, orig=userid1234567, input=userid1234567
```

What does the warning mean and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You get rid of the warning by passing in valid input.

You are calling [Validator.isValidInput(String context, String input, String type, int maxLength, boolean allowNull)](https://static.javadoc.io/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.1.0.1/org/owasp/esapi/Validator.html#isValidInput%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean%29)

You have the 'maxLength' parameter (the 4th parameter) set to 8. So you are telling this method that it should only return true if the 'input' parameter (your 2nd parameter in this method) has a length of <= maxLength.

Your logged output shows that you are passing it a value of 'userID' which is set to "userid1234567", which has a length of 13 characters. Thus the log message is correctly telling you that your input exceeds the maximum allowed length of 8 by 5 characters. In other words, it is doing exactly what it was designed to do.

Comment: sorry I should have written my question more specifically. I understand that I should get warrend one way or the other, that is not the problem. I was talking about the part `SECURITY FAILURE Anonymous:null@unknown -> /ExampleApplication/IntrusionDetector`. Beside that, after this warning I also get an exception: `org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidationException: issuer id: Invalid input. The maximum length of 11 characters was exceeded.` Can change the configuration so I only see the exception?

Comment: Well, first of all, if it said "maximum length of 11 characters", that must have been from a _different_ test, as the one that you originally illustrated had a max length of 8 characters.  But point taken. The only way that I know to get rid of the InstrusionDetector log entries is to disable it. Commenting out the line "ESAPI.IntrusionDetector=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultIntrusionDetector" using a leading '#' should do that.

Comment: Of course, OTOH, that will completely disable the IntrusionDetector, not just stop if for this one category. You could replace the DefaultIntrusionDetector with AppSensor (see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/AppSensor_GettingStarted). AppSensor allows much more granular configuration over what to alert on and threshold limits, etc. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/AppSensor_Developer_Guide for details.

Comment: @KevinW.Wall i know this is a very old answer and I'm facing the same problem, but wouldn't changing the log level configuration do the trick to hide the warnings without disabling the whole class? Like `<logger name="org.owasp.esapi" level="error" additivity="false">`

Comment: @FedericoPiazza, yes it would, if you are willing to disable all warnings from ESAPI logging. That seems a bit like throwing out the baby with the bathwater to me though. The next release of ESAPI (2.2.1.0, no tentative date yet, but I'm hoping it will be before the end of May at least) will has some additional properties in ESAPI.properties file that will help you control whether or not this output appears. It is already in the 'develop' branch.

Comment: @KevinW.Wall very nice, looking forward to seeing this release

Comment: @KevinW.Wall I know this is an old thread about ESAPI Intrusion Detector, My question is whether disabling IntrusionDetector would have any Security repercussions on other default ESAPI validation features, My understaning is that IntrusionDetector is used for logging purposes, but the actual validations are performed within other ESAPI layers (for instance XSS validation is done by the ESAPI SecurityWrapperRequest). To add more context to my question, i am using ESAPI 2.1.0.1 on a leagcy project and i would like to disable IntrusionDetector as it is slowing down the app. Thanks.

Comment: @Cypher - correct. Disabling the Intrusion Detector won't stop the security checks or change the exceptions when then get thrown, but it will stop many of those exceptions from getting automatically logged. If you wish to disable it, the easiest way is to set the ESAPI property 'IntrusionDetector.Disable' to 'true'.